# Constructing a Linked List with two data types in one node: Node<E,K>

Tags: java, data-structures

I have to convert my treemap that holds a key and a value to a linked list that holds a key and a value. For example:

```
1 100
2 200
```

etc.

But, how would I do this in a Linked List? I didn't think Nodes could hold the two different values. I don't so much as have code since I'm just struggling to get started. I can provide my treemap if it helps, but since it doesn't really apply...

Comment: Back it up a second... why do you think you have to go to a linked list? Give some background to your question. What's the [actual problem](http://xyproblem.info/) you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Make a class named `Pair<K,V>` and add it to the generic type of the `LinkedList<Pair<K,V>>`